# C++ reading function improvement to make read multiple files

Tags: c++, function, while-loop

I have a little improvement to make, I am making my turing machine, it reads parameters from txt file and then executes the tape in the terminal. What I want to do is to make it read from multiple txt files and execute multiple tapes then. Because I am new to programming it's difficult to me to understand whether I should use threads or make multiple reading functions and put the parameters into while loop later, maybe someone can give me an advice?

Here is the reading function

```
void reader(int &head, string &tape, string a[N][n])
{
    ifstream df;
    df.open("samples/1.txt");
    df >> head;
    df >> tape;
    rule = tape.size(); // how many symbols we have in our line
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        if (df >> a[i][0])
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
            {
                df >> a[i][j];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            length = i; //how many lines of rules we have
            i = N;
        }
    df.close();
}
```

And while loop

```
while (d != "X")
{
    for (int y = 0; y < length; y++)
        if ((d == a[y][0]) && (p == a[y][1]))
        {
            tape[position] = a[y][2][0];
            if (a[y][3] == "L") // if string equals L (or R) it switches/moves
                position--;
            else
                position++;
            p = tape[position];
            d = a[y][4];
            y = length;
        }
    for (int j = 0; j < rule; j++)
    {
        cout << tape[j];
        //Sleep(1);
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("CLS");
}
```

Comment: It all depends on how you want it to be. If you use loops, each file will be read after each other and then it will take a longer time to finish all the files. If you use threads, it's efficient in performance-wise. Then the runtime will be less. But if you're using `cout` to log, then it will look scattered. However, since you're using different files, and there won't be any mutex involved (hopefully), I suggest to go with threads.

Comment: Okay, thanks, but still I have to make my function read several files instead of one, but I can't find the right example of it

Comment: Where does this while loop fit in your code?

Comment: In the int main()

Comment: You don't need to create a new function for each file to read, just add a filename parameter and use that to open your files.

Answer (score 0):

C++ [std::thread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/) documentation is pretty straightforward.
Here is how you can achieve this.

```
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void doStuff(std::string fileName)
{
    // call your file reading and trigger the Turing Machine.
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> fileNames = {"file1.txt", "file2.txt"};
    vector<thread> threads;

    for ( string fileName : fileNames)
        threads.push_back(thread(doStuff, fileName)); // start a thread to run doStuff() with fileName as the argument.

    for (auto t : threads)
        t.join();

}
```

You can adjust your file reading to use the `fileName` in the `doStuff()` accordingly.

Comment: As far as I understand it should look something like this or am I wrong? Here is the code https://codeshare.io/adjPgB